# Excel Formula to Redistribute A Single Cell Value Over its Associated Rows When Groupings fluctuate from 1-1000 Rows in Large Data WorkSheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The best way to identify this question is with the example:  Below is a few sample rows.

I am trying to redistribute the $1532.50 by the % for all lines with the same Order # (016923) combined with simple single row Order's, which multiple the row % x Amount. My worksheet is 10 000+ Rows so cannot do this alternating calculation manually for each Order #.

2nd Issue is the amount of rows for each Order# fluctuation with no pattern. Order # 016923 has 6 Rows but some have hundreds.

ORD#     %        AMOUNT

016923 45.58%.........    $1532.50
016923    2.3%............. 0
016923    6.5%.............      0
016923  15.06%......... 0
016923   7.35%........... 0
016923  22.87% .........0
016972 100.00%........0
017059 100.00% ......$14,791.70

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, put your cursor anywhere in your table of data and press Ctrl+T to convert it into a structured table.

Next, add a column with this formula:

```
=SUMIF([ORD'#],[@[ORD'#]],[AMOUNT])*[@[%]]
```

This sums the amount by the order number on the current row then multiplies that sum by the percentage in the current row.

[image]

EDIT:

In case the sum of the percentages for the order number do not total 100%, (as is the case with ORD# 16923 in your sample data), and where you want to retain the full amount distributed across the visible rows, you can use this:

```
=SUMIF([ORD'#],[@[ORD'#]],[AMOUNT])*[@[%]]/SUMIF([ORD'#],[@[ORD'#]],[%])
```

[image]

If neither of those is the intention, and actually you are saying that $1532.50 represents 45.6% of the order total, and you want to extrapolate the other amounts, then you can use this to calculate the extrapolated amount for the order itself:

```
=IF([@AMOUNT]>0,[@AMOUNT]/[@[%]],0)
```

And this to calculate the item amount:

```
=SUMIF([ORD'#],[@[ORD'#]],[Extrapolated Order Total])*[@[%]]
```

Like this:

[image]

Note that this latter solution will only work if there is just one row per order number with an existing Amount.

Comment: The 1st/2nd example is the winner.  What a clean solution.  Game changing. Tks

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was helpful. Please consider accepting the answer if it was. Good luck with the project!